# Selenium Node + Sauce Labs Testing: Cannot Finish a Task

Tags: node.js, selenium, mocha.js, saucelabs

I'm using Sauce Labs to run my Selenium test scripts with Mocha as the testing framework. Scripts ran perfectly, but the problem is, the job does not finish - seems `driver.quit()` is ignored, and I'm prompted a timeout error after 90 secs.

Here's the code:

```
const { driver } = require('./config');
const { By, until } = require('selenium-webdriver');

describe('Integration test', function () {
  this.timeout(20000);

  it('can login as test user', function () {
    driver.get('https://www.example.com');
    driver.wait(until.elementIsNotVisible(driver.findElement(By.id('vale'))), 8000, 'Vale cannot fade');
    driver.findElement(By.name('email')).sendKeys('test_user@test.com');
    driver.findElement(By.name('password')).sendKeys('password');
    return driver.findElement(By.id('authFormSubmitButton')).click();
  });

  after(() => {
    console.log('Quiting driver');
    // This does not work!
    driver.quit();
  });
});
```

In the config a `driver` is built and connected to remote server.

When running this, in the console I can see the test passing and `Quiting driver` message, but in Sauce labs dashboard the task just keeps waiting until time out.

Btw I tested the above code with local `chromdriver` and everything works fine - `driver` is quitted immediately after the task.

Any help or idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needs a `return` before `driver.quit()`.

> Instead of calling done(), Mocha accepts a promise as return value. If
>   a test returns a promise, Mocha understands that it’s asynchronous,
>   and waits for the Promise to be resolved before passing to the next
>   test.

This [article](https://marmelab.com/blog/2016/04/19/e2e-testing-with-node-and-es6.html) is valuable.

Comment: this worked for me!